# How can we capture photo and upload on server in phonegap application

Tags: android, cordova, asp.net-mvc-4, phonegap-plugins

How can we capture photo and upload on server in phonegap application.

Server side code is mvc4 C# action.

We have to send two more values (name and ID) on server with image.

Comment: If you simply search you will find plenty of examples for this. Even the PhoneGap API doc has an example of how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to the android or phonegap piece, but for your MVC action, please look into `HttpPostedFileBase` - Haacked.com has a great article on it: http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I tried to ask a similar question but no response. Not sure if it can be done. There are a lot of PHP examples though.

[Working example of AJAX file upload to WCF service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13661105/working-example-of-ajax-file-upload-to-wcf-service)