# How to upload photo taken from camera using phonegap 2.2.0, jquery 1.8.3

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, mobile

How to upload photo taken from camera using phonegap, jquery

I am referring 
[Working example of AJAX file upload to WCF service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13661105/working-example-of-ajax-file-upload-to-wcf-service)

But ajax call is always getting into error function.